# Python - Elastic Bulk helper with delays between chunks

Tags: python, elasticsearch, iterator

On occasion I have to push 7k+ documents to my ES instance and doing it with a regular `bulk` operation from the `elasticsearch` library results in an error 413, meaning the payload I was pushing was too big for my instance to process.

Fair enough, I looked up the `helper` methods for elastic and found you can specify either the chunk size or chunk bytes and started fiddling with it -> [link to the official docs](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk). I noticed that now I am publishing the documents in chunks but there's **no delay** between the requests, i.e: if it needs to perform, say 50 requests, they will all be sent sequentially.

[image]

I was looking into these methods and see if I can add a delay before pushing each chunk but I didn't find anything relevant. The `elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk` does return an iterator but it's after every chunk has been pushed, and it's mainly to iterate over the results or if any error happened.

I am afraid the instance will get flooded or not be able to process every request. I can increase the chunk size to perform fewer requests, but the payload will be bigger of course.

Here's a snippet of what I am currently using. I am pushing chunks when there are 3000 docs or the chunk size exceeds 1 MB. These are just for testing if I could add a `time.sleep()` in between chunks, but the loop on the `bulk` is returning an iterator over the results as mentioned before:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import bulk, streaming_bulk
import time
class Test():
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self):
        if settings.ELASTIC_USER is not None:
            self.es = Elasticsearch(
                settings.ELASTIC_HOST,
                http_auth=(settings.ELASTIC_USER, settings.ELASTIC_PASS),
                use_ssl=False,
            )

        else:
            self.es = Elasticsearch(settings.ELASTIC_HOST, use_ssl=True)
...

def some_method():
    for info in bulk(
        self.es,
        self.generate_body_iterator(element, messages),
        raise_on_error=False,
        chunk_size=3000,
        max_chunk_bytes=1 * 1024 * 1024,
        max_retries=1
        ):
        time.sleep(1)
        errors = []
        for doc in info:
            if doc.get("index", {}).get("error"):
                data_error = doc.get("index", {}).get("error")
                data_error["post_id"] = doc.get("index", {}).get("_id")
                errors.append(data_error)
            if doc.get("update", {}).get("error"):
                data_error = doc.get("update", {}).get("error")
                errors.append(data_error)

        self.log.error(
            "Bulk insert failed ("
            + str(len(errors))
            + " errors): "
            + str(errors),
            True,
        )
        raise Exception("Bulk error")
```

The `generate_body_iterator` just `yields` a dict that feeds onto the helper function `bulk`.

Should I be concerned with making many requests to ES? Or doing fewer but with a bigger payload?